# Is it possible to integrate Zeppelin notes with git?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Is it possible to integrate Zeppelin notes with git?  One can set the repository location but how to set that to a remote git repository.

This functionality is however, available on Amazon EMR

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Yes. It's possible

I use following way.

#### Create a github repo and push all note book. like

```
git clone https://github.com/rockiey/zeppelin-notebooks.git
cd zeppelin-notebooks
cp -rf ../zeppelin/notebook/* .
git add -A
git commit -m "init"
git push
```

#### Delete notebook directory

```
cd zeppelin
rm -rf notebook
```

#### Clone github repo to notebook.

```
cd zeppelin
git clone https://github.com/rockiey/zeppelin-notebooks.git notebook
```

> While I still need push to github manually
>
> It would be great if zeppelin can connect a github repo directly

Comment: Thanks Rockie for helping me out with this.

Comment: I found that modify zeppein-site.xml is not necessary.

Comment: @Rochie Yang: How do you do individually for every notebook?