# Gitignore Zeppelin data

Tags: git, gitignore, apache-zeppelin

I've seen several resources about how to back up Zeppelin projects in git. (e.g. [Is it possible to integrate Zeppelin notes with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139089/is-it-possible-to-integrate-zeppelin-notes-with-git)).

However, none of them has made clear whether source code and data are stored in **separate files**, which would allow you to gitignore the data and only show "real" human-readable code changes to the notebook.

Is this possible? I think my question boils down to: does Zeppelin store data separate from code or is there some configuration that allows it?

**Note:** I haven't tried using Zeppelin yet - I'm just been researching it, but I have used Jupyter (IPython) notebooks and I know they mix code and data so you end up versioning data and arbitrarily refreshing meaningless outputs like graphics and instance ids etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using version 0.6.1 here, but everything so far has been in one json file, unfortunately. It's stored currently in "result" node. As a workaround, you can truncate note results since - I think - 0.7.0, using zeppelin API, so you can try and automate that to only see the code during inspection.